# Laravel query, show results from one table where their id isn't in another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, join

i have 2 tables users_teams and events_users

users_teams has all the user data (sample here)

- uid gid name
- 0   0   User A
- 1   0   User B
- 2   0   User C

events_users has when a user is at an event

- eid uid gid
- 0 0   0
- 0 1   0
- 1 1   1

I'm looking to write a laravel query to select any users from the users_teams that have a specified gid, and also aren't in events_users with a specified eid.

So for gid 0 and eid 0 i should get the details of User C

I thought an anti-join would work, but keep getting empty results. Can anyone help?

```
    $result = Users_team::where('users_teams.gid', '=', $gid)
                    ->leftJoin('events_users', function($join) use ($gid, $eid)
                        {
                            $join->on('users_teams.uid', '=', 'events_users.uid')
                            ->where('events_users.eid', '=', $eid);
                        })
                    ->whereNull('events_users.eid')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: ->whereNull('events_users.uid')   because there will no 'uid' in this case

Comment: $eid i thing must have an VALUE (here 0 ) and not NULL, http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/ lookpup LEFTJOIN example

Comment: same outcome unfortunately.

Comment: didn't konow the classes you use. cant u simplifiy the query ??

Comment: think it must be NULL, see Emma's row in the Left Join.

Comment: Yes in the result but not on the query!

Comment: ->where('events_users.eid', '=', $eid);  becomes:  events_users.eid IS NULL .  When $eid is really NULL when given as param

Comment: so it is an special case here in your classes so >whereNull('events_users.eid') is used, thing i got that right. Thing you should try your query first in normal SQL to get the right one and then move it partly to your methods

Comment: starting to think that the "where" inside the left-join isn't right. As when i remove that i do get a pretty good output, but only of users that aren't in the events_users table at all, i want to filter the results that they aren't in, if that makes sense

Comment: i thing im far away from helping here. If you can try to lookup the SQL that is build by your classes. maybe that helps to build a better query at all

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
$users = Users_team::whereRaw("uid NOT IN (SELECT uid FROM events_users WHERE gid = ? AND eid != ?)", [$gid, $eid])->get();
```

I tryed with this plain [SQL query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45cfc/4)

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Hey, that works! Thanks. Just wondering if anyone can do it without having to use Raw SQL, if not, i'll mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: Can you post your model declaration? sure this can be done with Eloquent. Ill will try another approach.